# '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' don't even know what the output has to

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'.
```

What do i need to change?

this is a simple python command, but, I'm new, so I can't fix it myself.

```
from math import *
n = input("set range:- ")
p = [2, 3]
count = 2
a = 5
while (count < n):
    b=0
    for i in range(2,a):
        if ( i <= sqrt(a)):
            if (a % i == 0):
                print("a neprost",a)
                b = 1
            else:
                pass

    if (b != 1):
        print("a prost",a)
        p = p + [a]
    count = count + 1
    a = a + 2
print(p)
```

I don't even know what to expect, but i can't continue learning if i won't fix this.

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: `input` function in python returns string object. Comparing `int` object with `str` object will raise TypeError(The issue is at `while (count < n):`)

Comment: Convert the input to int.       `int(input('set range:- '))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the line

```
count < n
```

`count` hear is an int (with value 2) but `n` which comes from the input argument is a string. Hence that is why you get the error. To fix the problem, convert `n` to an int by using the int function.

```
n = int(input("set range:- "))
```